# Populating JTable via tree map and SQL

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, treemap

I am populating a  JTable using a tree map and the tree map is being being populated via SQL, my problem is that i can only get in one line to populate via the tree map, is it possible to write a code(i.e counter) saying add a new line

this is the line of code:

```
library.put("01", new Item(res.getString(2),(res.getString(3), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(4))));
```

Comment: is it possible to write a code(i.e counter) saying add a new line == yes, don't to use HashWhatever as underlaying array for Swing JComponents/its model, use util.List instead (in the case that must be stored in separete array or twice)

Comment: Are you using a TableModel?

Answer (score 1):

> "is it possible to write a code(i.e counter) saying add a new line"

Sounds like to me you are holding data a in two separate data structures, one in your `TreeMap` and one in the underlying `TableModel` of the `JTable`. There's no need for this. Data should only be held in the `TableModel`. See more at [Creating a TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

The easiest way to go about adding a row dynamically is to use a `DefaultTableModel` which takes care of the `fireXxx` methods for you to update your table. You could write your own `XxxTableModel` using `Item` objects, but it may not be necessary.

For `DefaultTableModel` you can set the model with 0 rows (and just the column names) to start, if you have no initial data.

```
String[] cols = { "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3" };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(cols, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

If you *do* have some initial data, you can use the constructor

```
DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] cols)
```

Then to add rows dynamically, just use `model.addRow(Object[])`. Something like

```
Object[] row = { res.getString(2),
                 res.getString(3), 
                 Integer.parseInt(res.getString(4))
               };
model.addRow(row);
```

The table will be automatically updated for you by calling `addRow`.

The fact that you're using a `TreeMap` maybe says you want the data sorted. In that case you may want to look into [Sorting and Filtering Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)